# Why does Producer/Consumer threads demo hang on wrong place?

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I tried writing a Producer/Consumer threads demo, but it turned out wrong.

Consumer.class

```
public void consume(){
    if(TaskQueue.getInstance().isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("B1  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        synchronized (pruductMonitor) {
            System.out.println("B2  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            if(TaskQueue.getInstance().isEmpty()){
                //如果任务空了
                //唤醒生产者
                System.out.println("notify A    "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                pruductMonitor.notify();

            }
            System.out.println("B3  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            synchronized (customerMonitor) {
                System.out.println("B4  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                if(TaskQueue.getInstance().isEmpty()){
                    //挂起消费者
                    try {
                        System.out.println("B wait  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        customerMonitor.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("B running   "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        TaskQueue.getInstance().getTask();
    }
}
```

Producer.class

```
private void produce() {
    Bean b = new Bean();
    if (TaskQueue.getInstance().isFull()) {
        System.out.println("A1  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        synchronized (customerMonitor) {
            System.out.println("A2  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            if (TaskQueue.getInstance().isFull()) {
                // 如果队列满了，唤醒消费者
                System.out.println("notify B... "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                customerMonitor.notify();

            }
            System.out.println("A3  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            synchronized (pruductMonitor) {
                System.out.println("A4  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                if (TaskQueue.getInstance().isFull()) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("A wait  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        pruductMonitor.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("A running   "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        TaskQueue.getInstance().addTask(b);
    }
}
```

Main.class

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Object pruductMonitor = new Object();
    Object customerMonitor = new Object();

    TaskQueue.getInstance().setLimit(10);

      //生产者开动  
    new Thread(new Pruduct(pruductMonitor,customerMonitor)).start();  
    new Thread(new Pruduct(pruductMonitor,customerMonitor)).start();  
    new Thread(new Pruduct(pruductMonitor,customerMonitor)).start();  
    new Thread(new Pruduct(pruductMonitor,customerMonitor)).start();  
    //消费者开动  
    new Thread(new Customer(pruductMonitor,customerMonitor)).start();  
    new Thread(new Customer(pruductMonitor,customerMonitor)).start();  

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(true){
                System.out.println("==============="+TaskQueue.getInstance().getNum()+"===============");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

And the result is

===============9===============

A running   Thread-2

A running   Thread-0

A running   Thread-3

A1  Thread-1

A2  Thread-1

notify B... Thread-1

A3  Thread-1

A4  Thread-1

B running   Thread-4

A wait  Thread-1

A running   Thread-2

B running   Thread-4

===============9===============

B running   Thread-5

A running   Thread-0

A running   Thread-3

B running   Thread-5

B running   Thread-4

A1  Thread-3

A1  Thread-2

A1  Thread-0

===============10===============

B running   Thread-5

===============8===============

B running   Thread-4

===============6===============

B running   Thread-5

B running   Thread-4

===============4===============

B running   Thread-4

B running   Thread-5

===============2===============

B running   Thread-4

B running   Thread-5

===============0===============

B1  Thread-5

B1  Thread-4

B2  Thread-5

notify A    Thread-5

B3  Thread-5

===============0===============

===============0===============

===============0===============

===============0===============

===============0===============

Why after running pruductMonitor.wait() in Producer.class,all Producer threads hung on synchronized (customerMonitor) ,should it hang on synchronized (pruductMonitor) ?

Comment: `synchronized (a) {
     synchronized (b) {
     }
 }`

Comment: `synchronized (A) {
     synchronized (B) {
           wait;
     }
 }`
I think all Producer Thread hung on A , because the wait one had A ? And the Consumer Thread can  notify B,also hung A ! 
Oh, I know , Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You have several possible problems.

Always wait in a loop, like:

```
while (!somecondition) 
    somelock.wait();
```

Upon waiting the thread released the lock; once the thread wakes up and re-takes the lock it needs to check the condition again. A lot can happen between the time that a thread gets notified and wakes up and the time that that thread can get the lock, and the state that caused the thread to be notified may change again in that interval.

Second, acquiring multiple locks in one order one place and in the opposite order in another place is a good way to cause a deadlock. If what you want here is to make sure notify always affects relevant threads (consumers don't get notified for producer-related conditions and vice versa) it would be better to use a ReentrantLock with two separate Conditions than to juggle two intrinsic locks like this. See the API for the Condition class.

This is way too complicated, in large part because the locking is disassociated from the data structure being accessed. The purpose of locking is to protect the data structure from unsafe manipulation by the threads. Put the locking in the task queue, not in the producer and consumer, and this will become more manageable.